# How to separate possible URI from other content in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, scripting, uri

What is the simplest and fastest way to check if string is single URL or TEXT (that might contain urls)

possible scenarios:

```
// successful scenario
$example[] = 'http://sub-domain.my-domain.com/folder/file.php?some=param';
// successful scenario
$example[] = '/assets/scripts/jquery.min.js?v=1.4';
// successful scenario
$example[] = 'jquery.min.js';
// this scenario should fail validation
$example[] = "http://www.domain.com welcome text\n and some other http://www.domain.com";
// this scenario should fail validation
$example[] = "scriptVar=50;";
```

I have tried to use native php functions like parse_url, filter_var but non of them work as expected.

**UPDATE 1**

To make it more clear, I'm trying to separate possible URI from script content that would be inserted as DOM element. All urls would go as SRC attribute and rest as content, example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$string}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">{$string}</script>
```

**UPDATE 2**
By analysing possible content I come to conclusion that string containing white space character or semicolon mean that string could not be URI, I presume that this pattern could solve my problem:

```
preg_match('/[\s]|[;]/', $string);
```

would it cover all possible javascript/css code?

Comment: Define "URL". Will they always have the protocol prefix? If not, what would tell an URL apart from a random string - the `www.`? Do you want to test for http only or also ftp, scp, https...? What about username@password:hostname prefixes? What about relative URLs `/folder/file.php`?

Comment: You do know that, technically, both of those cases are valid URLs, right?  The difference is that the first one will probably result in a valid resource, while the second one will fail domain name validation/lookup.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, I forgot scenario without protocol or domain.

Comment: I have updated my examples, and yes cdhowie I understand that technically they are all valid URLs, one thing come at my mind that space character can be used as sign of text, however minified content such as javascript or css can fail this scenario.

Comment: Regarding update 2. I'm quite not getting what you're trying to achieve. You can use the DOM parser I provided in my latest update to iterate all elements in a DOM document. This includes scripts, styles, anchor-links, etc.

Comment: I'm building layout container that would generate HTML from array of properties and pass W3C validation in scenarios like HTML4, HTML5, xHTML, xHTML+RDFa and so on, for this reason I need to have control over tag attributes to be able to solve doctype conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$exampleData = Array(
    'http://sub-domain.my-domain.com/folder/file.php?some=param',
    '/assets/scripts/jquery.min.js?v=1.4',
    '<a href="/assets/scripts/jquery.min.js?v=1.4">',
    '<a href="assets/scripts/jquery.min.js?v=1.4">',
    'http://www.domain.com welcome text\n and some other http://www.domain.com',
);

foreach($exampleData as $example)
{
    echo "Trying \"" . $example . "\" -> ";

    echo (preg_match('%((http(s)?://|www\.)[^ \r\n]+|<a.+?href=(\'|")(http(s)?://|www\.|[^#])[^\4\r\n]*?\4.*?>)%i', $example)) ?
     "Match" : "No match";

    echo "\r\n";
}
```

This would produce:

```
Trying "http://sub-domain.my-domain.com/folder/file.php?some=param" -> Match
Trying "/assets/scripts/jquery.min.js?v=1.4" -> No match
Trying "<a href="/assets/scripts/jquery.min.js?v=1.4">" -> Match
Trying "<a href="assets/scripts/jquery.min.js?v=1.4">" -> Match
Trying "http://www.domain.com welcome text\n and some other http://www.domain.com" -> Match
```

**Update:**

After reading your last update. If you want to parse HTML. Use a DOM-parser like:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Example:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$dom = file_get_html('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');

foreach($dom->find('script') as $scriptElement)
{
    if(strlen(trim($scriptElement->src)) > 0)
    {
        // Script with URI set
        echo "<strong>Found script with URI</strong>";
        echo "<p>" . $scriptElement->src . "</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        // Script with content
        echo "<strong>Found script with content</strong>";
        echo("<p>" . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($scriptElement->innertext)) . "</p>");
    }
}
```

Would output something like(HTML stripped):

```
Found script with URI
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

Found script with URI
http://sstatic.net/js/master.min.js?v=afc76d4deac3

Found script with content    
var imagePath='http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/';
var inboxUnviewedCount = -1;

...etc
```

Comment: that is closer to what I'm looking for, but in my case third and forth  element in array should fail validation.

Comment: No, I'm building HTML container using DOMDocument and trying to create single method for SCRIPT tag instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

This function will return true if the passed text is an URL. It is based on a regex seen here on SO.

```
function validate_url ($url)
{
  $regex = '/^(https?|ftp):\/\/'; //protocol
  $regex .= '(([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;\?&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+'; //username
  $regex .= '(:([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;\?&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)?'; //password
  $regex .= '@)?'; //auth requires @
  $regex .= '((([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]\.)*'; //domain segments AND
  $regex .= '[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]'; //top level domain  OR
  $regex .= '|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}';
  $regex .= '(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'; //IP address
  $regex .= ')(:\d+)?'; //port
  $regex .= ')(((\/+([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)*'; //path
  $regex .= '(\?([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)'; //query string
  $regex .= '?)?)?'; //path and query string optional
  $regex .= '(#([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)?'; //fragment
  $regex .= '$/i';

  return (preg_match($regex, $url) ? true : false);
}
```

You can try it here: http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/validate_url

**EDIT** in response to comment, this function will validate URL fragments like /index.php or index.php

```
function validate_url_fragment ($url)
{
  $regex = '/^(((\/?([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)*'; //path
  $regex .= '(\?([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)'; //query string
  $regex .= '?)?)?'; //path and query string optional
  $regex .= '(#([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)?'; //fragment
  $regex .= '$/i';

  return (preg_match($regex, $url) ? true : false);
}

if (validate_url_fragment($url) || validate_url($url)) {
  //is url
} else {
  //not url
}
```

(note that the empty string is valid, so you may want a special case for that)

Answer (score 0):

`filter_var` should do what you want for a single URL:

```
<?php
$safe_url = filter_var( $unsafe_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL );
?>
```

Comment: FILTER_SANITIZE_URL will convert $text to valid URL and it is not what I'm trying to archive.

Comment: Then you should use: `if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))`

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_URL does not work as expected and would be fixed in future releases of PHP, it would always fail for domains containing hyphen